# How to configure socks5 proxy in irssi

Tags: irssi

I have been trying to configure irssi to run through a socks 5 proxy. In the documnetation there is no mention of how to use a socks5 proxy. Some threads the net say it can be done but there is no mention on how to do it. Also, these threads are atleast 3 to 4 years old.
I even tried running irssi through tsocks but it does not seem to be working

So, is it even possible to run irssi through a socks5 proxy and if so how do I do it?

Comment: I've been using weechat as an alternative to irssi and it's pretty good. I have faced no problems with proxy configurations.

Answer (score 1):

According to the irssi website, irssi needs to be compiled with socks proxy support, in order for that to work. The necessary compilation flag is --with-socks

source: http://irssi.org/beginner/
search for "socks"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question fully. The question is not only whether `irssi` can use a SOCKS proxy, but also how to get `irssi` to use **a particular** SOCKS proxy.